# unable to get data from http.post on php web service

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using angular to post data to PHP  JSON webservice but not able to get it correctly

here is my code for .http method

```
    app.controller('AddCustomer',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){
$scope.freshRequest = true;
$scope.addCustomer=function(){
    var data_to_send={};
    data_to_send.name=$scope.name;
    alert(data_to_send.name);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../service/add_new_Customer.php', 
        data: data_to_send,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(returnedData){
        $scope.freshRequest = false;
        $scope.response = returnedData.response;
        $scope.accountNumber= returnedData.accountNumber;
        $scope.updatedBalance= returnedData.updatedBalance;
        $scope.transactionSuccessful = returnedData.transactionSuccessful;          
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
        console.log($scope.status)});



};}]);
```

below is the htm form that I am using to call the addCustomer() method

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate ng-controller="AddCustomer as add" ng-submit="addCustomer()">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" ng-model="name">
<input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" ng-model="fname">
 <button id="button1id" type="submit" name="button1id" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

my php is getting  null for the field name when i am doing  $_REQUEST['name'] or $_POST['name'];

below is the php code

```
<?php
class Summary{
   public $response= "Account Could not be added invalid data";
   public $transactionSuccessful= "";
   public $updatedBalance= "";
   public $accountNumber= "";
}
$e = new Summary();
$final_res =json_encode($jsonObj) ;
if( $_REQUEST['name'] ){
$e->response =  $_REQUEST['name'];
}
else{
$e->response =  "Account Could not be added invalid data";
}
 $e->transactionSuccessful= true;
$e->updatedBalance=  $_POST['name'];
$e->accountNumber=  $_POST['name'];  
echo json_encode($e);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to decode the posted data to json and then you can access the properties of the object. `file_get_contents("php://input")` allows you to read the raw posted data. This is how you would get name.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$name = $request->name;
```